# Jupyter notebook and macOS High Sierra: "osascript: can't open default scripting component"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, macos-high-sierra

jupyter-notebook was working fine until I upgraded to macOS High Sierra. Anyone know how to resolve the "osacript: can't open default scripting component" problem? Searching this site and Google yielded no answers. I'm on Anaconda 4.3.24. Thanks.

```
$ jupyter notebook
[I 08:12:13.340 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 08:12:13.360 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/Greenhorn/Local/projects
[I 08:12:13.360 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 08:12:13.360 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/?token=9d8bde3a675f28b3cbc4c87b7eb0c36788b4d28260d9ed39
[I 08:12:13.360 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 08:12:13.361 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=9d8bde3a675f28b3cbc4c87b7eb0c36788b4d28260d9ed39
osascript: can't open default scripting component.
```

Comment: I have the exact problem by running Anaconda on High Sierra. Did you solved the problem already?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into exactly the same problem with `osascript` whilst diagnosing an issue with Emacs Applescript integration (Emacs reports the error as `do-applescript: OSA language not available`, but further debugging led me to `osascript` and its `can't open default scripting component`). I also recently upgraded to High Sierra.

Online one unfortunately finds too much advice that an OSX re-install is required.

In my case, a reboot fixed the issue.

You can diagnose by running the test command:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Hello, World!"'`

After the reboot, this should popup a "Hello, World!" dialog.

Comment: I rebooted but still there's an error: osascript: can't open default scripting component